# Computing the metric tensor under a coordinate transformation

Tags: tensors, differential-geometry

I am try to compute the metric tensor under under a coordinate transformation, using the formula:

> \begin{align} g_{\mu'\nu'} = \frac{\partial x^{\mu}}{\partial x^{\mu'}} \frac{\partial x^{\nu}}{\partial x^{\nu'}}  g_{\mu\nu}, \end{align}

where $g_{\mu\nu}$ is the diagonal metric $(-1, 1, r^2, 1)$ for cylincdircal coordinates. The coordinates transformation equations are given in the code. Here's the code:

```
metric1 = {{-1, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 1, 0, 0}, {0, 0, r^2, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 1}};

n = 4;

tPrime[t_] := t;

rPrime[r_] := r;

\[Theta]Prime[\[Theta]_, t_] := \[Theta] - \[Omega]*t;

zPrime[z_] := z;

coordold = {t, r, \[Theta], z};

coord = {tPrime, rPrime, \[Theta]Prime, zPrime};
```

When I try and execute `Table[g[M, N], {M, 1, 4}, {N, 1, 4}] // MatrixForm`I get the zero matrix, which isn't the correct answer.

What could be going wrong?

Comment: Well, you define the coordinates with argument, but in `coord` you refer to them without arguments...

Comment: I change `coord` to `coord[t_, r_, \[Theta]_, z_] := {tPrime[t], 
   rPrime[r], \[Theta]Prime[\[Theta], t], zPrime[z]};`. Now I get the error, `SetDelayed::write: Tag List in {tPrime,rPrime,\[Theta]Prime,zPrime}[t_,r_,\[Theta]_,z_] is Protected.`

Comment: Got it, thanks.

Comment: I am not quite sure, but it seems that you turned your transformation matrix upside-down.

Comment: @AlexeiBoulbitch Yes, I corrected that mistake as well. Apparently, Mathematica doesn't automatically invert the linear system of equations (of course, why would it do automatically), so I made that correction. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Try using this code

```
ClearAll["Global`*"];

n = 4;
coord = {t, r, \[Theta], \[Phi]};

\[Eta] = {{-1, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 1, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 1, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 1}};
\[Eta] // MatrixForm;

"e-Metric";
e = {{-1, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 1, 0, 0}, {0, 0, r^2, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 1}};
e // MatrixForm
dete = Det[e];
inve = Inverse[e];
inve // MatrixForm
detinve = Det[inve];

Answer := Answer = Simplify[Table[Sum[
     D[D[e[[\[Mu], \[Nu]]], coord[[a]]], coord[[b]]]
     , {\[Mu], 1, n}, {\[Nu], 1, n}]
    , {a, 1, n}, {b, 1, n}]]
listAnswer := 
 Table[If[UnsameQ[Answer[[a, b]], 0], {ToString[Ans[a, b]], 
    Answer[[a, b]]}] , {a, 1, n}, {b, 1, n}]
TableForm[Partition[DeleteCases[Flatten[listAnswer], Null], 2], 
 TableSpacing -> {2, 2}]
```

The trick to differentiating a metric is to define a 'coord' then refer to it. I had to use a different variable $a$ and $b$ instead of $\mu'$ and $\nu'$ respectively

Answer (score 1):

Here is my solution. This works for the spherical coordinate system but can be generalized for any other system as well. This example is for the FLRW in the spherical polar coordinates and it gives back the metric in the cartesian coordinates.

```
ncoor={t,x,y,z};
r[x_,y_,z_]:=Sqrt[x^2+y^2+z^2];
\[Theta][x_,y_,z_]:=ArcTan[Sqrt[x^2+y^2]/z];
\[Phi][x_,y_,z_]:=ArcTan[y/x];
ocoor={t,r[x,y,z],\[Theta][x,y,z],\[Phi][x,y,z]};
oldmet={{1,0,0,0 },{0,-a[t]^2,0,0},{0,0,-a[t]^2 r^2,0},{0 ,0,0,-a[t]^2 Sin[\[Theta]]^2 r^2}};
newmet=Simplify[Table[\!\(
\*UnderoverscriptBox[\(\[Sum]\), \(\[Alpha] = 1\), \(4\)]\(
\*UnderoverscriptBox[\(\[Sum]\), \(\[Beta] = 1\), \(4\)]\(oldmet[[\[Alpha]]]\)[[\[Beta]]] D[ocoor[[\[Alpha]]], ncoor[[\[Mu]]]] D[ocoor[[\[Beta]]], ncoor[[\[Nu]]]]\)\),{\[Mu],1,4},{\[Nu],1,4}]/.Sin[\[Theta]]->Sqrt[x^2+y^2]/r/.r->Sqrt[x^2+y^2+z^2]]
```

This definitely is not the most elegant way of going about it. But it works nevertheless. This gives the following answer

```
{{1, 0, 0, 0}, {0, -a[t]^2, 0, 0}, {0, 0, -a[t]^2, 0}, {0, 0, 
  0, -a[t]^2}}
```

Comment: Please provide your code in Mathematica format rather than as an image.

Comment: Here is the code.